# How to extract a single frame while retenaing transparency from a transparent video

Tags: ffmpeg, transparency

I'm trying to extract a single frame from a transparent webm video while retaining transparency.

I tried doing this:

```
ffmpeg -i input.webm -frames:v 1 -pix_fmt rgba output.png
```

This extracts a frame with a white background and no transparency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a FFmpeg build with `libvpx` support.

You can then override the default decoder to correctly retrieve the alpha channel.

VP8:

```
ffmpeg -codec:v libvpx -i input.webm [...]
```

VP9:

```
ffmpeg -codec:v libvpx-vp9 -i input.webm [...]
```

Comment: Yes, that did it. It's kinda odd the decoder has to be specified like that.